# onItemClickListener for multiple row listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have List View with multiple items(header,event item). I use On Item Click Listener, it get position of each items.but I want position of group(both header,event item). I used this tutorial http://antew.com/?p=162? ..please help.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your `onListItemClick` listener you get the position of the item clicked. Use this number to fetch the row type from your adapter. In other words

```
private void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id){
 MyListAdapter.RowType type = RowType.values()[adapter.getItemViewType(position)];
 switch(type){
    case MyListAdapter.RowType.HEADER_ITEM:
    // do stuff
    break;
  }
 }
```

Hmm after reading again your question it seems that my answer is incomplete. If I understood correctly you want to know that e.g. the 3rd item of the 2cnd group was clicked, right?
In that case I would write a method in the adapter like this

```
public int getGroupPosition(Item item, int position){
  RowType type = RowType.values()[getItemViewType(position)];
  switch(type){
    case RowType.HEADER_ITEM:
      int headersCount = 0;
      // count the headers before the one clicked
      for(int i=0; i < position; i++){
        if(RowType.values()[getItemViewType(i)] == RowType.HEADER_ITEM){
          headersCount++;
        }
        return headersCount + 1;
      }
    case RowType.LIST_ITEM:
      int listItemsCount = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<position; i++){
         if(RowType.values()[getItemViewType(i)] == RowType.HEADER_ITEM){
           // reset the counter so we find the position of the item
           // inside the group
           listItemsCount = 0;
         }else {
           listItemsCount++;
         }
      }
      return listItemsCount + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with RowType. before the HEADER_ITEM and LIST_ITEM (I edited my answer).

Comment: RowType is in enum.so type mismatch..it show cannot convert to int error.

Comment: Edited and added RowType.values()[x] which should convert an int to the enum. I hope it works.

Comment: hi,your coding is for find each items position in list.but i want     [header & item1,2]-position1,[header & item1,2,3]-position2  ..jus like this..